# Eclipse 3.8 on Linux Mint missing new software and plugins

Tags: linux, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, linux-mint

I work with Eclipse (3.8, repository version) on Linux Mint 16, and used to have CDT and a bunch of other tools. Yesterday I tried to install some plugins for web development, and after installation and reset, Eclipse hung up on startup. So I tried to remove the lockfile ($ rm -r workspace/.metadata), but now all my plugins are missing! Including my CDT plugins. I can only make a generic General project or load one from a CDT.

Help, please?

Answer (score 2):

Due to licenses, the eclipse published in the repository is not the regular eclipse we use to know.

Try downloading the eclipse that you need directly from: 
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Use a folder to untar the file, like /opt/. This is going to be the location where your application will be.

i.e.

```
sudo tar zxvf eclipse-standard-kepler-R-linux-gtk.tar.gz -C /tmp
sudo mv /tmp/eclipse /opt/eclipse_cpp
```

I use /opt/eclipse_cpp for my cdt installation. I do not like to combine plugins for several languages in the same application. I had problems with some cpp plugins in the past.

Comment: Thanks, but are you sure it would save my issue though? It sounds like an issue I could work out with my current version of Eclipse, I'm just not really sure how.

Comment: I would try to discard this problem installing eclipse from eclipse.org. The option is to have the list of plugins or tools that you are installing to try to help you replicating the problem.